# How do I inflate and read zip files using zlib?

Tags: ruby, zlib, unzip

How do you unzip a file, or read the contents of a zip file in order to select what to extract?

The  `.pencast` is zip compressed, so I can use the following in bash:

```
unzip -j *.pencast "*.aac"
```

But in Ruby:

```
require 'zlib'

afile = "/Users/name/Desktop/Somepencast.pencast"
puts afile

def inflate(string)
  zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new
  buf = zstream.inflate(string)
  zstream.finish
  zstream.close
  buf
end

inflate(afile)
```

results in:

```
/Users/name/Desktop/Somepencast.pencast
prog1.rb:11:in `inflate': incorrect header check (Zlib::DataError)
  from prog1.rb:11:in `inflate'
  from prog1.rb:17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: [How do I get a zipped file's content using the rubyzip library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236810/how-do-i-get-a-zipped-files-content-using-the-rubyzip-library)

zip and gzip are different protocols and need different unzipping software.

*Personally* I find rubyzip a bit of a pain to use, so I would be inclined to consider just shelling out to the unzip command you're already using. You can do that with

```
`unzip -j *.pencast "*.aac"` # note backticks
```

or

```
system( 'unzip -j *.pencast "*.aac"' )
```

(or various other ways)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was so easy to run bash commands in Ruby... I'm aware that zip and gzip are different, but I'm surprised Ruby does not have an in-built for zip. gzip may be 'better' but zip is so common!. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can read a ZIP file's entries and optionally read its contents.  This example will print the contents of the `README.txt` entry from the zip file named `foo.zip`:

```
require 'zip/zip'
zipfilename = 'foo.zip'
Zip::ZipFile.open(zipfilename) do |zipfile|
  zipfile.each do |entry|
    puts "ENTRY: #{entry.name}" # To see the entry name.
    if entry.name == 'README.txt'
      puts(entry.get_input_stream.read) # To read the contents.
    end
  end
end
```